# incompatible types when assigning to type 'atomic_int' from type 'int'

Tags: c, ffmpeg

```
src/libavcodec/h264_slice.c: In function 'ff_h264_execute_decode_slices': src/libavcodec/h264_slice.c:2757:36: error: incompatible types when assigning to type 'atomic_int' from type 'int'
                 sl->er.error_count = 0;
                                    ^ src/libavcodec/h264_slice.c:2781:48: error: invalid operands to binary
+ (have 'atomic_int' and 'atomic_int')
                 h->slice_ctx[0].er.error_count += h->slice_ctx[i].er.error_count;
                                                ^ make: *** [libavcodec/h264_slice.o] Error 1 make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

I compile ffmpeg for android. whether the problem is my environment configure or source code?

Comment: Are you linking against `atomic` lib and using `c++11`?

Comment: In ffmpeg, `atomic_int` is a typedef of `intptr_t`, which requires C99. Which compiler are u using?

Comment: ~/develop/ffmpeg/ffmpeg_git/configure --prefix=~/develop/ffmpeg/ffmpeg_install --cross-prefix=/home/wanzhipeng/android/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --target-os=linux --extra-cflags="-isystem/home/wanzhipeng/android/bionic/libc/include -isystem/home/wanzhipeng/android/bionic/libc/kernel/uapi -isystem/home/wanzhipeng/android/bionic/libc/kernel/uapi/asm-arm -isystem/home/wanzhipeng/android/bionic/libm/include -fpie -std=gnu99" --extra-ldflags="-B/home/wanzhipeng/android/out/target/product/msm8909/obj/lib/ -pie"

this is my command.

Comment: I try to add  -stdgnu99, no effect.

Comment: Sorry but that's not helpful. Configuration flag won't work if your compiler doesn't know that flag or not support c99.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is source code problem. I change it as below:

sl->er.error_count = 0;
***atomic_store(&sl->er.error_count, 0);***

h->slice_ctx[0].er.error_count += h->slice_ctx[i].er.error_count;
***atomic_fetch_add(&h->slice_ctx[0].er.error_count, atomic_load(&h->slice_ctx[i].er.error_count));***